# Error when submit spring-boot application to spark

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-spark, gradle

My spark cluster is running in standalone mode.

I was deploying a spring-boot application to the spark cluster with spark-submit and I encountered this error:

I removed several jars in spark/jars that are incompatible with my spring-boot jar, such as gson and servlet-api.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.10.10.53, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)

...
```

My command:

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master spark://localhost:7077 \
path_to_jar/xxx.jar
```

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.3.RELEASE'){
        exclude module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.1.3.RELEASE'){
            exclude module: 'logback-classic'
            exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.1.3.RELEASE')

    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5')
    compileOnly(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.7.7'){
        exclude module: 'servlet-api'
    }
    compileOnly(group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.0')
    compileOnly(group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.12', version: '2.4.0')


}
```

SparkContext is autowired in the spring-boot application.

SparkContextBean.java

```
@Configuration
public class SparkContextBean {
    @Autowired
    private SparkProperties sparkProperties;


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(SparkConf.class)
    public SparkConf sparkConf(){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(sparkProperties.getAppname());

        return conf;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(JavaSparkContext.class)
    public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() throws Exception {
        return new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf());
    }


}
```

Spark code:

```
//hsidata is a JavaPairRDD<Integer, short[][]> value
Tuple2<double[], double[]> mk = hsidata.mapToPair(pair -> {
    short[][] data = pair._2;
    return JTool.CalcMK(data);
}).reduce((right, left) -> {

    double[] mean = right._1;
    int bands = mean.length;
    double[] K = right._2;
    int n = bands * (bands + 1) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++)
        mean[i] = mean[i] + left._1[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        K[i] = K[i] + left._2[i];
    return new Tuple2<>(mean, K);
});
```

Comment: Please provide sample spark application code to help this issue

Comment: code has been updated, thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test spark application standalone mode in your local machine, set master as **local**.

```
bin/spark-submit --master local path_to_jar/xxx.jar
```

I suspect that you might run different spark version than you built the jar. Please make sure that spark version installed in your machine is 2.4.0.

If you still face issues, please post the sample spark sample computation application code.

Comment: The program works at the local model, but it fails when I try to run it on the cluster. My spark version is 2.4.0.